# How to exit a loop (while loop) with an if statement from a function called within the loop?

Tags: function, variables, loops, if-statement, while-loop

So like:

```
void aLoop(){
   int i = 0;
   while(i < 10){
      aFunction();
      i++;
   }
}

int aFunction(int i){
   if(aVariable == 1){
      i = 10;
   }
   if(aVariable != 1){
      statement;
      statement;
      i = i;
   }
   return i;
}
```

Where aFunction() will be called for each i (0,1,2,3,...,9) and for each call will satisfy either the first if statement or the second.

Assuming all functions and variables are declared, would this be able to stop the while loop if aVariable == 1?

How else could you accomplish the same thing?

I'm really inexperienced with programming.

FIXED:

```
void aLoop(){
   int i = 0;
   while(i < 10){
      i = aFunction(i);
      i++;
   }
}

int aFunction(int i){
   if(aVariable == 1){
      i = 10;
   }
   if(aVariable != 1){
      statement;
      statement;
      i = i;
   }
   return i;
}
```

Comment: You didn't mention what language you're using.

Comment: Use the `break` or `return` statement of your chosen language.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
aFunction(x);
```

just use

```
i = aFunction(x);
```

Comment: You should probably pass i as an argument to aFunction as well.

Comment: LoL sure, missing in the original, missing in the response :) I just added it, thx GavinH

Comment: Thanks! In my program, I had both aFunction(i); AND i=aFunction(i). I assume they were conflicting.

Comment: Yes, just change the name of one of them. Functions must be called by a representative name. aFunction is not a very good name... try to name the function by something that represents what the function does.

Comment: And if you fixed the code with my answer, plz mark it as solution

Answer (score 0):

use return to terminate a method.

USe break to terminate a for/ while loop or in a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void aLoop(){
     int i = 0;

    do{
       aFunction();
       System.out.print(i+" ");
        i++;
    }while(i < 10);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested solution under "FIXED" will work but if you wrote a large program using this approach you'd end up with software that would be very complex and very costly to work on. This is because `aFunction` is dependent on the function `aLoop` that calls it. Functions should ideally be independent of each other, whereas `aFunction` only works if it's being called from a while loop. You almost never want a called function to be dependent on the structure of the function that calls it.

Try to code so that the the responsibilities or "intentions" of each part of the program are clear, so that any dependencies are minimal and obvious. E.g. here you could write

```
void aLoop(){
   bool continueProcessing = true;
   for(int i=0;
       continueProcessing && i < 10;
       i++) {
       continueProcessing  = aFunction(i);
   }
}

int aFunction(int i){
    bool stillProcessing = aVariable != 1;
    if (stillProcessing) {
        statement;
        statement;
    }
    return stillProcessing;
}
```

Of course, in `aLoop` there are some other options which amount to the same thing. You could carry on with a `while` loop (I think `for` is clearer). Also, you could `break` out of the loop instead of having an extra `continueProcessing` variable.

```
void aLoop(){
   for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (!aFunction(i))
          break;
   }
}
```

Finally I'm not sure you even need to pass the variable `i` into `aLoop`. If you don't, or some other data is more appropriate, it would be better to change this too.

Comment: Well the program that I am writing would use aFunction() ONLY in that loop (while i<10). Then I have another one (for i=10; i<20; i++), etc. that calls different functions with slightly different statements. And, yes, I know to make the names of variables and functions correspondent to the intentions, but I was just simplifying mine down to an easier-to-read version.

Comment: @user3259381 OK, I would still try to reduce the coupling between the loop and the function it calls. Think of it like the called function gets a message from the callee and sends a message back saying "call me again", or "don't call me again". But I also take your point that you have put in some effort to simplify your question and may have done it so well that I have got the wrong end of the stick!